# Mongodb partial index on one of the indexed field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I want to create partial index on one of the indexed field
but I am failing miserably

```
db.Comment.createIndex(
 { "siteId": 1,
 { { "parent": 1} ,{partialFilterExpression:{parent:{$exists: true}}}},
 "updatedDate": 1,
 "label": 1 } 
);
```

how to do that?

the field "parent" is the one I want to index partially

In roboMongo I get the error
**Error: Line 3: Unexpected token {**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the `partialFilterExpression` object as a second parameter to `createIndex`. See [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/).

```
db.Comment.createIndex(
  { "siteId": 1, "parent": 1, "updatedDate": 1, "label": 1 },
  { partialFilterExpression: { parent: { $exists: true } }
);
```

So don't think of it as partially indexing a field; your partial filter expression defines which documents to include in your index.